# Proper way to handle playing mp3 in external storage

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to play an mp3 in the emulator's external storage (but not on an sd card). After some Googling I thought I had code that would work and also added the following lines to my app's AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

It still fails and I found posts saying that apparently I need to request permission as well. Copied in some code I found that was supposed to do so but then I got a message from Android Studio saying that using it would limit what API level it would work with. Realized then I was way out of my depth on what is the right way to accomplish my goal. Some context for what API level is reasonable or sanity checking of my MediaPlayer code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    private lateinit var mp: MediaPlayer
    private var totalTime: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate( savedInstanceState: Bundle? )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState )
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main )

        // this is the permission code I get the API level warning about
        val MY_READ_EXTERNAL_REQUEST : Int = 1
        if (checkSelfPermission(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), MY_READ_EXTERNAL_REQUEST)
        }

        mp = MediaPlayer()
        // path and name of mp3 file I'm trying to play
        mp.setDataSource( "/storage/emulated/0/Music/Bad Guys Win.mp3" )
        mp.prepare()
        mp.start()
    }
}
```

Permission Error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.scratch/com.example.scratch.MainActivity}:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Music/Bad Guys
>   Win.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

[Screenshot of API warning from Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeKIf.png)

Comment: Given that [you do not have filesystem access to that directory on Android 10+ by default](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), I recommend that you switch to querying the `MediaStore` and using a `Uri` obtained from it.

Comment: I am facepalming right now. When I was reading the MediaPlayer docs I misread "Internal URI" as "Internal URL" and thought the code given there was another type of streaming (like the External URL example). Thanks for helping out this noob!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for permission, but you are not waiting for it to be granted. Use this callback method which is automatically called after a permission is granted:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if(grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults.get(0) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        // write your media player code here
    }
}
```